# How do I delete a record if the primary key is not named 'id'? (CakePHP 2.x)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

How do I delete a record in CakePHP 2.x when I am using an auto increment primary key named `users_id` instead of `id`?

I am using the following code:

```
$this->User->delete(12);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: which version of cake? What error do you get? How you set your model?

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare in your model the name of the field you will be using as primary key. For example:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    // user_id is the field name in the database
    public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```

The following should now work:

```
$this->User->delete(12);
```

This syntax is also allowed:

```
$this->User->id = 12;
$this->User>delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

With the `deleteAll()`method you can specifiy conditions like you would do in a query.
So in your case it would be

```
$this->User->deleteAll(array('User.user_id' => 12));
```

refer to http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html for more details

Comment: Can you explain what is user , findByEmail and visitor in cakephp.

$this->User->Visitor->findByEmail

Comment: The cakephp `findBy()` functions that return the item specified in brackets, e.g. $this->User->VisitorfindByEmail('test@email.com'); returns a visitor with the email specified in brackets. It is just a short version for $this->User->Visitor->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Visitor.email' => 'test@email.com')));

see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#findby